# Grouped linear regression in Spark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm working in PySpark, and I'd like to find a way to perform linear regressions on groups of data.  Specifically given this dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
pdf = pd.DataFrame({'group_id':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],
                    'x':[0,1,2,0,1,5,2,3,4,5],
                    'y':[2,1,0,0,0.5,2.5,3,4,5,6]})
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pdf)

df.show()
# +--------+-+---+
# |group_id|x|  y|
# +--------+-+---+
# |       1|0|2.0|
# |       1|1|1.0|
# |       1|2|0.0|
# |       2|0|0.0|
# |       2|1|0.5|
# |       2|5|2.5|
# |       3|2|3.0|
# |       3|3|4.0|
# |       3|4|5.0|
# |       3|5|6.0|
# +--------+-+---+
```

I'd now like to be able to fit a separate `y ~ ax + b` model for each `group_id` and output a new dataframe with columns `a` and `b` and a row for each group.

For instance for group `1` I could do:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
# Regression on group_id = 1
data = df.where(df.group_id == 1).toPandas()
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(data.x.values.reshape(len(data),1), data.y.reshape(len(data),1))
a = regr.coef_[0][0]
b = regr.intercept_[0]
print('For group 1, y = {0}*x + {1}'.format(a, b))
# Repeat for group_id=2, group_id=3
```

But to do this for each group involves bringing the data back to the driver one be one, which doesn't take advantage of any Spark parallelism.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so could you show us your efforts? It is not exactly clear what is the input here, how do you convert it to Spark data structures, and what kind of tool you want to use to create models.

Comment: What is `group_id`?, Which are the features and which are the labels? Do you wan to use `ML` or `MLLib`?

Comment: I've edited to clarify what I'd like to do - in this case the only feature is `x`.  Happy to use `ML` or `MLLib` or anything else that might be appropriate.

Comment: Is that even possible with Pandas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a solution I found.  Instead of performing separate regressions on each group of data, create one sparse matrix with separate columns for each group:

```py
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint, SparseVector

# Label points for regression
def groupid_to_feature(group_id, x, num_groups):
    intercept_id = num_groups + group_id-1
    # Need a vector containing x and a '1' for the intercept term
    return SparseVector(num_groups*2, {group_id-1: x, intercept_id: 1.0})

labelled = df.map(lambda line:LabeledPoint(line[2],
                groupid_to_feature(line[0], line[1], 3)))

labelled.take(5)
# [LabeledPoint(2.0, (6,[0,3],[0.0,1.0])),
#  LabeledPoint(1.0, (6,[0,3],[1.0,1.0])),
#  LabeledPoint(0.0, (6,[0,3],[2.0,1.0])),
#  LabeledPoint(0.0, (6,[1,4],[0.0,1.0])),
#  LabeledPoint(0.5, (6,[1,4],[1.0,1.0]))]
```

Then use Spark's `LinearRegressionWithSGD` to run the regression:

```py
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LinearRegressionModel, LinearRegressionWithSGD
lrm = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(labelled, iterations=5000, intercept=False)
```

The weights from this regression contain the coefficient and intercept for each `group_id`, i.e.

```py
lrm.weights
# DenseVector([-1.0, 0.5, 1.0014, 2.0, 0.0, 0.9946])
```

or reshaped into a DataFrame to give `a` and `b` for each group:

```py
pd.DataFrame(lrm.weights.reshape(2,3).transpose(), columns=['a','b'], index=[1,2,3])    
#           a              b
# 1 -0.999990   1.999986e+00
# 2  0.500000   5.270592e-11
# 3  1.001398   9.946426e-01
```

Comment: Very elegant solution. I wonder how the performance would difference vs applying a `sklearn` regression within a `mapPartitions` call when a lot of 'groups' are present.

Comment: Very nice solution, but will it scale to hundreds of thousands of groups?

Comment: How would one use VectorAssembler with this solution?

Answer (score 1):

Two other solution options:

- For your specific use case (single variable) the closed form solution is a simple formula composed of sums, sums of squares and sum of cross terms (sum(x*y)). You can compute squares and multiplications first, and then aggregate them into sums for each group using standard groupby+aggregate. Then you use these terms to compute the coefficients using the appropriate formula for each group on the already grouped and much smaller dataframe.
- For general case of linear regression with many columns and no mood for implementing closed-form solution as above, you can use groupby and collect_list to collect the data into groups and then use sklearn regression wrapped into UDF for each group. This way you will achieve parallel execution of the linear regressions across different groups, but no cluster-level parallelism inside each of the regressions + you have some costs related to using python UDF. It might or might not be good solution, depending on the number of groups, group size and partitioning. This is probably more or less similar to what @kirk-broadhurst proposed in a comment above.