# spark train distributed model per group

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, group-by, apache-spark-sql

How can I train a distributed machine learning model in spark for each group inside a data-frame (obtained after a group by key operation)?

sparklyR offers this convenience function:

> http://spark.rstudio.com
>
> ```
> spark_apply(
>   iris_tbl,
>   function(e) broom::tidy(lm(Petal_Width ~ Petal_Length, e)),
>   names = c("term", "estimate", "std.error", "statistic", "p.value"),
>   group_by = "Species"
> )
> ```

but is something similar possible in the regular scala API?

I have heard that a collect / weka /... might be suggested, but this has the downside of not allowing distributed training.

Is there a way to also allow for distributed training of grouped models? For linear regression [Grouped linear regression in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33999156/grouped-linear-regression-in-spark) is a great workaround, but what about tree based models?

Comment: isn't that the same as [udaf](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udaf-scala.html)'s?

Comment: Partially, but usually, these only work for single records ad a time. Not for an entire dataframes like MLLIB works on when performing machine learning.

Comment: Equivalent function in SparkR is `gapply()`. In Scala, you can achieve the same via `mapGroups()` or `flatMapGroups()` on `KeyValueGroupedDataset`: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.KeyValueGroupedDataset

Comment: Indeed, but I would like to use the scala API and also use mllib distributed models

Comment: Using distributed models (such as the ones in mllib) on each group doesn't make sense, if you think about it. What you are asking for is kind of "nested" parallelism. One level of parallelism is the level of groups, and the other level is processing each group in distributed manner. Even `gapply()` (also, the corresponding function in sparklyR) assumes that data in each group is small and the training function is executed on a single machine/worker.