# spark loop in matrix to run linear regression

Tags: scala, apache-spark, matrix, linear-regression

I have a spark data frame `dt` as below. BAB is ID and I would like to run a linear regression with column AAB and AAD for every value of BAB.

[image: data frame]

This is how I run it. By filtering the whole dataframe for every BAB value, it gets really slow. Is there a way of looping the data like a 3-dimensional matrix and running a regression for every BAB? So that I need to go through BAB once only. It does not have to be spark mllib. Any other machine learning tool with scala coding is fine.

```
val arrColu = Array("AAB", "AAD");
val assFeat = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(arrColu).setOutputCol("features");

val arrBAB=dt.select("BAB").collect.map(_ (0)).map(x => x.toString);

for (a<-0 to arrBAB.length-1){

val vecDF: DataFrame = assFeat.transform(dt.filter("BAB='"+arrBAB(a)+"'").select("AAB","AAD"));
val lr1=new LinearRegression();
val lr2=lr1.setFeaturesCol("features").setLabelCol("AAD").setFitIntercept(true).
  setMaxIter(10).setRegParam(.3).setElasticNetParam(.8);
val fitD1=lr2.fit(vecDF);
...
}
```

Comment: is there a `distinct` missing in the code when collecting `arrBAB`?

Comment: yes i shoud have added .distinct(). Still there could be more than 5000 distinct BAB's. So better to loop it only once instead of filtering the whole data frame for every BAB

Comment: maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34104050/2129801) can help?

Answer (score 1):

One way is converting the data frame into a list with tuples as element `List((BAB1,AAB1,AAD1),(BAB2,AAB2,AAD2),...)`, then slicing the list w.r.t each individual `BAB` and running regression on each slice.