# LinearRegressionWithSGD Spark 3 (Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to implement something similar to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33999156/grouped-linear-regression-in-spark) using Spark 3.2.0 and Scala; however, I'm having trouble using the [LinearRegressionWithSGD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/regression/LinearRegressionWithSGD.html) class. It seems that in [Spark 2.3.1](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LinearRegressionWithSGD) this class had a constructor; however, that constructor has been removed:

```
Spark context Web UI available at http://localhost:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1674256005591).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.2.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.12.15 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 11.0.12)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LinearRegressionWithSGD;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LinearRegressionWithSGD

scala> val lrm = new LinearRegressionWithSGD()
<console>:43: error: constructor LinearRegressionWithSGD in class LinearRegressionWithSGD cannot be accessed in class $iw
       val lrm = new LinearRegressionWithSGD()
                 ^
```

I tried finding a constructor, using a builder or factory method and didn't discover anything.

I have looked but haven't been able to find any documentation on how to use this class using the new version of Spark and am wondering how to do so. Please let me know if you can help! Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if it helps but there's a `LinearRegressionModel` in the same file which is public. I guess they are related somehow.

Comment: Yes, the constructor is not accesible out of the mllib package. Use import org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression instead.

Comment: Hi @EmilianoMartinez thank you for the comment. I'm hoping to use `LinearRegressionWithSGD` because of the interface. Specifically I want to call [run](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/regression/LinearRegressionWithSGD.html#run) as in the example posted. [org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/regression/LinearRegression.html) doesn't have this method.

Comment: the ml api allows to include the same parameters, it works with dataframes instead of RDD[LabeledPoint]